# Django after login failed page is not redirecting to next

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

If user do successfull login then it is redirecting to next but if user can not do login then I wants to change template and wants to redirect to next page but it is not working.

Views.py

```
def login(request, template_path='login.html'):
"""
"""
# We'll only allow staff to view this page after login.
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('home')

if request.method == 'POST':

 if request.META['HTTP_REFERER'].split('/')[-1] == 'bs5':
        template_path = 'theme/bs5_theme.html'

    response = LoginView.as_view(
        template_name=template_path,
        redirect_field_name='next',
        form_class=EmailAuthenticationForm,
    )(request)

    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(dict(success=True, next=request.POST.get("next"))),
                content_type="application/json"
            )
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(False), content_type="application/json")
    else:
        return response
else:
    form = auth_forms.AuthenticationForm()
    model = dict(login_form=form)
    return render(request, template_path, model)
```

login.html

```
    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    Login failed. Email and password case-sensitive.
                </div>
    {% endif %}  
<form id="formLogin" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post" role="form">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/bs5" />
            <label for="id_username" class="form-label">Email address</label>
            <input type="username" class="form-control" id="id_username" name="username" value="{{ form.username.value }}">
            <label for="id_password" class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="id_password" name="password">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

I have also try with

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/bs5')
```

But then it is not showing login error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What to do you mean by redirecting to the next page in case of an unsuccessful login? Could you please be a bit more specific about your requirements?

Comment: Page which is mention in next hidden field in login form.

Comment: how do you think users will visit this link? I can't seem to any bit of `javascript` in the above snippets that do this for you?

Comment: There is not any javascript. All I want to do if user is not authorized then redirect to another url rather than login page.

Comment: okay, you will have to do that from your `view` function. Can you please post your complete `view` function which is handling this request?

Comment: I have add complete view function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to redirect a user who couldn't log in to a different page, one of the ways that you may do it is:

```py
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def login(request, template_path='login.html'):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
         redirect('home')

    user = authenticate(request, username= request.POST.get('username'), password=request.POST.get('password'))
    if user is not None:
          next_url = request.POST.get('next') # get your next url
          messages.error(request, _('Invalid credentials')) # display login error on the next page
          return redirect(next_url)
    else:
         login(request, user)
         # redirect to the successful url that you wish to
```

For more information on displaying messages in your template, you may consult [django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages)

Comment: Getting error: 
authenticate() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 3 were given.
I also try to import authenticate as different function name

Comment: i have updated the call to authenticate, both the parameters `username` and `password` should be password as keyword.

Comment: it is still redirecting to login page rather than /bs5 which I have passed in next url

Comment: We have to write return redirect(next_url)

Comment: In next page is there any way that I can detect error?

Comment: yes, thanks for the edit about `return redirect`. what kind of error?

Comment: Means we are sending error message so I wants to add some other code if error is detected.

Comment: No one but I don't know how to do it. How can I detect that there is error as it is directly adding element to html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235064/discussion-between-abhyudai-and-patel887).